# Android: Monkey with web apps

Tags: android

I want to test web app on android and I want to use Monkey tool. Is it possible to say to Monkey to send touch events only to Browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly works on a device. I just gave Google some fairly random input. :-)

```
adb shell monkey -p com.google.android.browser -v 500
```

The key is the `com.google.android.browser` part. That *should* give you the stock browser, if it exists on the device. If you are uncertain what the package name is for the browser you want to test with, you can find that out via [AppXplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.AppExplore&hl=en).

That being said, I am uncertain how effective Monkey will be here, as it will also invoke the menu and so on. And, when I tried it on an emulator, Monkey couldn't find the browser, which I found curious.

At any rate, you are certainly welcome to experiment further.